# Swipe back moves multiple scenes

Tags: react-router, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

**Setup**

> "react": "16.0.0-alpha.3",
>
> "react-native": "0.43.1",
>
> "react-native-router-flux": "^3.26.16"

**Expected behaviour**

On swipe back gesture, I expect to animate single scene only and go back by that scene.

**Actual behaviour**

From time to time (+- 50%), swipe back gesture animates 1 or multiple scenes. Despite it animates multiple scenes while swipe back is in progress, it goes back by single scene in every situation.

[image: enter description here]

**Steps to reproduce**

Give following scene hierarchy, do swipe back gesture

```
<Router createReducer={createNavigationReducer}>
  <Scene key="auth" component={RootScene} hideNavBar initial={true} />
  <Scene key="sceneLogin">
    <Scene key="sceneLogin1" component={LoginScene} title="Login" renderLeftButton={renderLeftButton} />
  </Scene>
  <Scene key="sceneRegister">
    <Scene key="sceneRegister1"
      component={RegistrationScene} title="New User" renderLeftButton={renderLeftButton} />
    <Scene key="sceneRegister2"
      component={RegistrationScene2} title="New User2" />
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

**Reducer (basic)**

```
export const createNavigationReducer = (params) => {
  const defaultReducer = Reducer(params);
  return (state, action) => {
    if (__DEV__) {
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      if (console.group) console.group('Navigation:');
      console.log('ACTION:', action);
      if (console.groupEnd) console.groupEnd();
      /* eslint-enable no-console */
    }

    console.log(defaultReducer(state, action));
    return defaultReducer(state, action);
  };
};
```

**Navigation actions**

// Root view (with "New User" button)

> New user -> Actions.sceneRegister

// New User scene

> go next -> Actions.sceneRegister2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `panHandlers={null}` on your Scene.